# Set-ADComputer ExtesionAttribute1 on an array of computers in another domain (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, dns

How can I use `PowerShell` to `Set-ADComputer ExtesionAttribute1` on an array of computers in another domain?

Comment: Use the `-Server` parameter to target a DC in the other domain

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you've tried already?  @MathiasR.Jessen is correct, but it would be easiest if we could show you how to implement into your specific script.

Comment: Set-ADComputer -identity "$server" -Server "$DNS_Host_Name" -replace @{ExtensionAttribute1 = "$changeIt"}

Comment: Thank You, Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you will need credentials for the remote domain and run Set-ADComputer with -Server pointing to a Domain Controller in that domain:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Computers = Get-Content c:\ListOfComputers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
Set-ADComputer -Identity $Computer -Credential $Credentials -Server RemoteDC -Add @{extensionAttribute1="myString"}
}
```

Comment: Glen,  Will I absolutely require -Credentials?  I am testing this now.  And, I believe that your help has made this happen.  Waiting for the "change" to happen

Answer (score 1):

I work in an environment with 13 domains, so this is a pretty common thing I run into... what Glen explained above would the the proper way to accomplish this task. You'll store your credentials for the remote domain in a variable and then loop through each of the computers and issue the set-adcomputer cmdlet to change the attribute. If you have A LOT of servers I'd recommend using jobs to issue the set cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Both contributors(Mathias R. Jessen  and Glen Buktenica) Solved my issue.
I had split my commands to NO avail.
When I added the -Server argument to my Set-ADComputer function call.  The change was reflected in the correct computer & correct Domain!

```
Set-ADComputer -identity "$server" -Server "$DNS_Host_Name" -replace @{ExtensionAttribute1 = "$changeIt"}
```

I had tried dozens of attempts.
Thank You for Helping me.  You Guys are Brilliant! TGIF